# Need to correct the "friction"/travel distance of balls in a billiard game, in processing

Tags: processing

Hey guys I am in the process of building this simple billiard game, and I want the black ball, labeled bBall, to go the same distance as the white ball, labeled wBall, and no farther. ie, if the white ball travels 20 pixels before it hits the black ball, I want the black ball to travel 20 pixels and then stop. How might I go about accomplishing this? Thanks for the help guys.

processing 2.0.3

```
ball wBall, bBall;
int click;
String msg;
Boolean moving = false;
float difx, dify;
float cdistance;
int steps = 40;
void setup(){
   click=0;
   size(800,400);
   background(16,77,27);
   wBall = new ball(35,#ffffff);
   bBall = new ball(35,#000000);
   msg="";
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(!moving){
 click++; 
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(16,77,27);
  String msg;
  fill(0,0,0);
 ellipse(15,15,30,30); 
 ellipse(785,15,30,30);
 ellipse(15,385,30,30);
 ellipse(785,385,30,30);
 ellipse(410,15,30,30);
 ellipse(410,385,30,30);
 msg="the count is "+click;
 println("the count is "+click);
 //Moving Balls\\
 fill(255,255,255);
 noStroke();  

 if(click==0){
       wBall.xpos=mouseX;
       wBall.ypos=mouseY;
 }else if(click==1){
       bBall.xpos=mouseX;
       bBall.ypos=mouseY;
 }else if(click==2){
       difx = wBall.xpos-bBall.xpos;
       dify = wBall.ypos-bBall.ypos;
 }
  else if(click==3){
 cdistance = dist(wBall.xpos,wBall.ypos,bBall.xpos,bBall.ypos);
   if (cdistance>bBall.ballDiam/2){
       moving = true;
       wBall.xpos-=difx/steps;
       wBall.ypos-=dify/steps;
   }
   else{
      moving = false;
      click=4;
      println("click"+click);
   }
 }else if(click==4){
  if(cdistance<bBall.ballDiam){
    moving = true;
    bBall.xpos-=difx/steps;
    bBall.ypos-=dify/steps; 
  }
 }
 wBall.update();
 bBall.update();
}

class ball{
  float xpos, ypos;
  color myColor;
  int ballDiam;
  boolean visible = true;
  ball(int tempdiam, color tempColor){
    myColor=tempColor;
    ballDiam=tempdiam;
  }

   void update(){
   if(visible){
    fill(myColor);
    ellipse(xpos,ypos,ballDiam,ballDiam);
   }
  }
}
  void keyPressed(){
   if (key =='c'){
    setup();
   } 
}
```

Comment: This might be better on the stack exchange site for game design...though it is a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make your

```
 else if (click==4) {
    if (cdistance<bBall.ballDiam) {
      moving = true;
      bBall.xpos-=difx/steps;
      bBall.ypos-=dify/steps;
    }
  }
```

to

```
 else if (click==4) {
    if (cdistance<bBall.ballDiam) {
      if (dist(wBall.xpos, wBall.ypos, bBall.xpos, bBall.ypos) < sqrt(sq(difx)+sq(dify))) {
        moving = true;
        bBall.xpos-=difx/steps;
        bBall.ypos-=dify/steps;
      }
    }
  }
```

essentially only moving the ball as long as its distance from the white one is less than the original difference...

Despite this though I feel you are approaching this the hard way. Maybe take a look to introduce speed and acceleration (and maybe even friction) calculations to your game and things will make more sense...